# Selection and Popups on Overlapping/Coincident Vector Layer Polygons in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, popup

I have a GeoJSON file of polygons that I am bringing into my OpenLayers session.  Some of the polygons occupy the same space on the map.  I am using a select control and popup control like:-

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(geojson_layer,
{
    onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect,
    clickout: true, toggle: true,
    multiple: false, hover: false,
    toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
    multipleKey: "shiftKey" // shift key adds to selection
});
map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
geojson_layer.events.on(
{
    "featureselected": function(e) 
    {
        showStatus("selected feature "+e.feature.attributes.APPREF+" on  Applications");
    },
    "featureunselected": function(e) 
        {
        showStatus("");
        }
    });   
        function onFeatureSelect(feature) 
        {
            selectedFeature = feature;
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble
            (   
                "chicken", 
                feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                null,
                "<div style='font-size:.8em'><b>App Reference: </b>" + feature.attributes.APPREF +"<br><b>Proposal: </b><br>" + feature.attributes.PROPOSAL+ '<br><a href="localhost:8080/ApplicationDetail.aspx?Ref='+feature.attributes.APPREF+'" target="_blank">Further Details</a>'+"</div>",
                null, 
                true, 
                onPopupClose
            );
            feature.popup = popup;
            popup.autoSize = true;
            popup.minSize = new OpenLayers.Size(150,50);
            popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(250,150);
            //popup.panMapIfOutOfView = true;
            popup.closeOnMove = true;
            map.addPopup(popup);
        }
        function onFeatureUnselect(feature) 
        {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }
```

Where more than 1 polygon occupies the same space - can anyone advise how I allow for drilling down and/or making the other features at the location available for a popup (and therefore the link out for further information).

I suspect the answer lies somewhere in Z-indexing, but can't wrap my head around how I would integrate that from the example thats provided.

Presumably there is a way of handling this type of scenario - if someone could enlighten me that would be very much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with stock OpenLayers. But there is a [pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/174) with an alternative to the SelectFeature control, which applies to both OpenLayers 2.12 and current master. Using events, that FeatureAgent should notify you of all features that you hit with a click.

Minor caveat: when your features are rendered with the Canvas renderer, only the topmost feature will be hit - like with the SelectFeature control. But with SVG and VML renderers you will be fine.

Comment: thanks this looks interesting - are you aware of any examples out there implementing this?  Or are there any guides for what parameters I need to pass.

Comment: Look at the `feature-events.js` example in the pull request. You can modify the geometries to overlap.

Comment: thanks for this, can't get it working at the moment on the example but suspect that its what I'm after.